# Do Python Tkinter frame have limitation on maximum number of widget it can hold

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, scrollable

I am try create a simple scrollable frame But while doing I noticed number of widgets display in inner frame is not exceeding 1559.
Is there any restriction or limitation for frame that it can only 1560 widgets vertically ??

```
from Tkinter import *

def con(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

window = Tk()
outframe =  Frame(window,width=300,height=300,bg="red")
outframe.pack()
canvas = Canvas(outframe,width=200,height=200,bg="blue")

inframe = Frame(canvas,width=200,height=200,bg="red")
bar = Scrollbar(outframe)
bar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=bar.set)
bar.configure(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=inframe,anchor='nw')
inframe.bind("<Configure>",con)
for i in range(2000):
    Label(inframe,text=str(i)).grid(row=i,column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not a limit on widgets, it's a limit on the coordinate space I think; +/-32767 pixels or so.

Comment: I suspect it has more to do with the maximum height of the frame. If you pack the labels into multiple columns, (for example, by doing `Label(inframe,text=str(i)).grid(row=i/10,column=i%10)`), then the 2000 labels will all be rendered without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the size of the canvas, which imposes a size limit on the things in the canvas.